# Disabling occlusion culling in BGE hides nearby objects

Tags: game-engine, camera

I am making a game which you can get [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sidedvirusartandanimation/games/undead-fields). I was editing different system settings in Blender to fix my one-digit framerate issues. I disabled the occlusion culling option in the world settings and now the game runs at a stable 60 FPS. I have one problem though. Any nearby objects, such as my zombies, will disappear if I get too close to them. Also, all HUD items which are parented to my camera disappear except for my text. I checked my camera clipping settings and it's at 0.25 blender units for the near one. It's not even that I can see through a close part of the zombie like you'd expect. I mean that they just completely vanish until I get far enough away. This is really annoying. Is there any way that I can have occlusion culling disabled to boost my performance but at the same time not have any near objects disappear? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the character that my camera was parented to was scaled which in turn scaled my camera. I applied the scale of my player and cleared the scale of my camera and now this problem is fixed.